# TypeScript compile error while using EventEmitter

Tags: typescript

I am getting below compile error for below code,

Error,

Error   TS2322  Type 'EventEmitter<{}>' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.

```
@Output()
ratingChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
```

Please suggest how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: ratingChange:`EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ratingChange` is of generic `EventEmitter<number>` type but the instance you are creating is of non-generic `EventEmitter`. The below should work:

```
ratingChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```